# What does "wouldn't be exaggerating to say" mean?

Tags: meaning

[Example](http://www.vancouverdesi.com/news/nridiaspora/south-asian-doctor-finds-fruit-extract-that-may-cause-cancer-cells-to-kill-themselves/817669/):

> "It is very potent, which is surprising, actually," said Pandey. "I **wouldn’t be exaggerating to say** it's a little bit better than dandelion root extract."

Why not just say "It is very potent. It's a little bit better than dandelion root extract." Why the need to add "*I wouldn’t be exaggerating to say*"?

Comment: "*wouldn’t be exaggerating*" means exactly what it means as it is written!

Comment: Would you also ask the meaning of "She wouldn't be unhappy to help you", "They wouldn't be unfair to prefer jazz than rap", "It wouldn't be silly to dance in the crowd", "There shouldn't be any objection from the owner, if we photographed their pretty little house".

Answer (score 1):

The full context of the text you quoted is as follows:

> A University of Windsor anti-cancer crusader may have discovered his most effective agent yet — a fruit that causes evil cells to commit suicide.
>
> Dr. Siyaram Pandey, known for promising work on dandelion root extract, is thrilled with results from his initial research on long pepper fruit.
>
> “It is very potent, which is surprising, actually,” said Pandey. “I wouldn’t be exaggerating to say it’s a little bit better than dandelion root extract.”

Evidently, Dr Pandey's work with long pepper fruit follows on from some previous work he did involving dandelion root extract that the article describes as having been 'promising'.

In this context, when Dr Pandey says “I wouldn’t be exaggerating to say it’s a little bit better than dandelion root extract”, his point is not merely that his pepper fruit extract is *potent*; it is his comparison of the *superiority* of the pepper fruit extract (which he says he is not exaggerating) in relation to a different preparation that appeared to have some potential in its own right.